# Set current Sprint or close existing sprint in Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, agile

Used JIRA for a long time and have moved to Visual Studio Team Services.

How do you close the existing sprint and start the next ..the dates ending does not automatically roll it forward to the next

We are using SCRUM

Comment: It looks like @Esther Fan - MSFT edited out the TFS content from this question, but the TFS tag was left in. Is the TFS tag now outdated, or is TFS a subset of VSTS (or the other way around)?

Comment: No, TFS still applies to the on-premises product. So I'm removing the TFS tag because this thread was originally about VSTS, which is the cloud version and separate from TFS. Thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

TFS can be very confusing when it comes to sprint ends.

I have found that the best way to make it work is to ensure that you have several sprints configured, with the end date of one being followed the day after by the start date of the next.

If there is a gap between the sprint dates then the previous sprint stays 'current' up until the day on which the next sprint starts.

So something like this:

> Sprint 1: 8th June - 21st June
>
> Sprint 2: 22nd June - 5th July
>
> Sprint 3: 6th July - 19th July

Note that there is no manual way to close a sprint. You have to do it with the dates.

Comment: ahh... ok ..I didnt have a start date for the NEXT sprint so even after the end date had elasped it still stayed in the SPRINT 1

Comment: I came from JIRA to TFS as well and was really surprised how difficult this was to do!

Comment: Actually, you can manually close the sprint, but you will risk being unorganized because it will ask you to move the tasks from the closing sprint to another, or to the top level of the iteration. To do so... From the dashboard, hover the the __gear/cog__ icon and click on __Work__. You then can manually close/delete sprints from there.

Answer (score 7):

I start a new iteration also automated via the start date. The old iteration remains marked as **Current** until the start date of the next iteration is reached.

- Iteration 1: 8th June - 21st June
- Iteration 2: 22nd June - 5th July

The Items are moved manually from Iteration 1 to Iteration 2.

Further Iteration settings in VSTS can be found in the current VSTS design under

- **Project settings > Work > Team configuration > Iterations**

Note: Each iteration will have a backlog and board.

Answer (score 4):

In the VSTS web app:

1. Click on the project/team combo (upper left corner).
2. Click on the gear (blue bar).
3. Click the "Work" tab.
4. Add an iteration (if you don't already have the new one created).
5. Under "Backlog iteration", press "Change" and select the desired iteration.
6. Profit.

An even faster way is to change the ending of the VSTS URL to:

```
%20Team/_admin/_work?_a=iterations
```

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd leave here my solution in case it helps others.

This is all available in [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/07/20/how-to-add-iterations-in-visual-studio-team-services-vsts/)

**1) create the iteration**

- go to: /_admin/_work?_a=iterations
- create a new iteration
- make sure the current date falls within the start date and end date

**2) associate the iteration**

- go to /Your%20Team/_admin/_work?_a=iterations
  (or click "default team's settings" in the previous url)
- click "Select iteration(s)" and then pick the iteration you just created

[image]

[image]

**3) view the current sprint**

- go to /_backlogs/Iteration/
- this link will show the current, active sprint
- sprints don't appear to have an "active" flag, they will be activated based on the current date